# Can UNet do Rigidbody2D prediction? (i.e. using gravity)

Tags: unity, interpolation, movement-prediction, unity-networking

Having a `NetworkTransform` with `transformSyncMode` set to `SyncRigidbody2D` (as opposite to a plain `SyncTransform`) I assumed it would try to sync all physics, hence handling gracefully forces, especially gravity.

What I got instead, is a very simple linear interpolation, which smooths out the gravity, so that jumping up and down looks incredibly unnatural: I would have expected this wish a `SyncTransform` of course, but, given the name I would have expected `SyncRigidbody2D` to solve this sort of problem…

So, am I missing something and might I have some value set wrong, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SyncRigidBody2D will also update velocity and angular velocity (if syncSpin is set to true). It will not however, also sync the entire state of the physics simulation, just of the synced body.

One way to reduce pulsing would be to use curved interpolation to match the start and end velocities, however it seems Unity's NetworkTransform script does a linear interpolation.